# Почему не получается использовать Identity и Cookie authentication одновременно?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть база данных с логинами и паролями, по которой авторизирую пользователей с помощью cookie. Но в ней есть не все пользователи. Я решил добавить в проект Identity, с помощью которой выдавать свои учетки для таких случаев. Вот чем проблема: после введения Identity авторизация по кукам перестала работать.

Я создал два отдельных проекта и убедился, что по отдельности эти механизмы работают, но совместно работает только Identity. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ совместить оба этих механизма?

Авторизация по кукам:

```cs
        private async Task Authentificate(User user) 
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim> 
            {
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, user.Role?.Name),
                new Claim("company", user.Company.Name)
            };

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
        }
```

Код класса Startup (без строчек контекста):

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
                });
        }

        public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```